# image don't render in react (django + react with vite project )

Tags: reactjs, django, vite, map-function, image-rendering

Hello I'm trying to develop a blog using django as a backend and react on the frontend. i've written a map function on the frontend to loop through the blog articles, all other field elements appears but the images don't render.
the following are some files that i think might be relevenat for this case

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

# Create your models here.

class Category (models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Categories'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Post (models.Model):
     
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    body = models.TextField(null=True)
    published = models.DateTimeField('Date published', auto_now_add=True)
    modified = models.DateTimeField('Date published', auto_now_add=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, default="", verbose_name='Categories', on_delete=models.SET_DEFAULT )
    author = models.ForeignKey(get_user_model(), default=1, on_delete=models.SET_DEFAULT)
    image = models.ImageField(default='default/no_image.png', upload_to='blog/%Y/%m/%d', max_length=255)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

serializer.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from .models import *

class CategorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Category
        fields = '__all__'

class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = '__all__'

class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = '__all__'

class UserRegSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    username = serializers.CharField(max_length=150)
    username = serializers.CharField(max_length=100, write_only=True)

    def create(self, validated_data):
        user = User.objects.create(
            username = validated_data['username'],
            password = validated_data['password']
        )

        return user
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name='home'),
    path('category/', views.category, name='category'),
    path('users/', views.users, name='users'),
    path('user-registration/', views.user_registration, name='user-registration'),
]
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework import status
from .serializers import *
from .models import *
from django.contrib.auth.models import  User

# Create your views here.

@api_view(['GET'])
def home (request):
    posts = Post.objects.all()
    serialize = PostSerializer(posts, many=True)
    return Response(serialize.data)

@api_view(['GET'])
def category(request):
    cat = Category.objects.all()
    serialize = CategorySerializer(cat, many=True)
    return Response(serialize.data)

@api_view(['GET'])
def users(request):
    users = User.objects.all()
    serialize = UserSerializer(users, many=True)
    return Response(serialize.data)

@api_view(['POST'])
def user_registration(request):
    serializer = UserRegSerializer(data=request.data)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        user = serializer.save()
        return Response(serializer.dat, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    
    return Response(serializer(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST))
```

Home.jsx

```
import React, {useEffect} from 'react'
import { useDispatch, useSelector} from 'react-redux'
import { getPostStatus, selectAllPosts, getPostError, fetchPosts } from '../features/blog/BlogSlice'
import BlogExcerpt from '../features/blog/BlogExcerpt'
import SidePannel from './SidePannel'


const Home = () => {

  const dispatch = useDispatch()

  const posts = useSelector(selectAllPosts)
  const postStatus = useSelector(getPostStatus)
  const errors = useSelector(getPostError)

  useEffect(() => {
    if (postStatus === 'idle'){
      dispatch(fetchPosts())
    }
  },[dispatch, postStatus])

  let content;
  if (postStatus === 'loading'){
    content = <div className='center'>
      loading...
    </div>
  } else if (postStatus === 'succeeded'){
    content = posts.map((post) => 
      <BlogExcerpt key={post.id} postId={post.id} post={post}/>
    )
  }else if (postStatus === 'failed')
{
  content = <p>failed {errors} </p>
}

console.log(content)
  return (
    <div className='container m-auto mt-5'>
        <div className='grid grid-cols-3 gap-4'>
            <div className='col-span-2 shadow-lg text-center pl-12 py-3'>
               <div className='container px-auto grid grid-cols-2 gap-2'> { content } </div>
               <img src='http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/blog/2024/02/17/team-1.jpg' alt='web' />
               
            </div>
            <div className=''>
                <SidePannel/>
            </div>
        </div>
        
    </div>
     

  )
}

export default Home
```

BlogExcerpt

```
import React from 'react'

const BlogExcerpt = ({post, postid}) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <p>{post.title}</>
      <img src={post.image} alt='yep' />
    </div>
  )
}

export default BlogExcerpt
```

BlogSlice.jsx

```
import axios from 'axios';
import { createAsyncThunk, createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';


const apiUrl ='http://127.0.0.1:8000';


const initialState = {
    posts: [],
    status: 'idle',
    error: null,
    categoryFilter: null,
}

export const fetchPosts = createAsyncThunk('post/fetchPosts', async () => {
    const response = await axios.get(apiUrl);
    return response.data
});

const postslice = createSlice({
    name: 'posts',
    initialState,
    reducers: {
        setCategoryFilter: (state, action) => {
            state.categoryFilter = action.payload
        },
    },

    extraReducers(builder){
        builder
            .addCase(fetchPosts.pending, (state, action) => {
                state.status = 'loading';
            })
            .addCase(fetchPosts.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
                state.status = 'succeeded';
                state.posts = action.payload;
            })
            .addCase(fetchPosts.rejected, (state, action) => {
                state.status = 'failed';
                state.error = action.error.message;
            })
    }
})

export const {setCategoryFilter} = postslice.actions;

export const selectAllPosts = (state) => state.posts.posts;
export const getPostStatus = (state) => state.posts.status;
export const getPostError = (state) => state.posts.error;
export const selectCategoryFilter = (state) => state.posts.categoryFilter;

export default postslice.reducer;
```

in fact when i inspect the img element, the source url is "http://localhost:5173/media/blog/2024/02/17/team-1.jpg" however, i think the url should have been "http://localhost:8000/media/blog/2024/02/17/team-1.jpg". in fact when i enter this later url I'm able to retrieve the image as it is th actual url to the media folder in the django backend.
any help would be greatly appreciated.